# No such module 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'

Tags: swift, cocoapods, iqkeyboardmanager

New to Xcode (dabble a little). I paid a developer to build an iOS app for me. He sent me the source code and I have opened it in Xcode 13.2.1. I needed to edit the info.plist to include a description why location was required (got this done). When I try to run the build, I get the error 'no such module 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'. In AppDelegate, I see 'import IQKeyboardManagerSwift --- No such module 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'. I went to the Podfile directory and ran 'pod install'. Output says:

- Analyzing dependencies
- Downloading dependencies
- Generating Pods project
- Integrating client project
- Pod installation complete! There are 7 dependencies from the Podfile and 8 total pods installed.

I'm still getting the error when trying to run the build. I tried cleaning the build folder and running the build again but still, same error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this happens, but one way to solve your issue is to go into your build settings and define the Framework Search Paths to a folder that contains the frameworks in question. If the frameworks are placed in your project directory, simply set the framework search path to $(SRCROOT) and set it to recursive.

Comment: Looks like the PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH is set to ${SRCROOT}/., so is PODS_ROOT. Not sure if I'm looking at the right thing, kinda new to Xcode :)

Comment: I got this notice when I ran 'pod install' [!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `IQKeyboardManagerSwift` to `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-IQKeyboardManagerSwift/Pods-IQKeyboardManagerSwift.debug.xcconfig` or include the `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-IQKeyboardManagerSwift/Pods-IQKeyboardManagerSwift.debug.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Target Support Files/IQKeyboardManagerSwift/IQKeyboard..

Answer (score 0):

Is the codebase completely in Swift?, else you will have to include import in the **Bridging header file**
If in swift you can try:
Select project name -> Select Build Settings(tab) and search **Framework Search Paths** double click and set the desired path($(SRCROOT)) to recursive

Answer (score 0):

The missing module handles a number of keyboard behaviors so you don't have to reinvent that wheel.  Check out the developer's website and get it for yourself.  I've been using it for years.  The developer has helped me more than once get past some obstacles.